# Cannot connect two users to windows's VPS's VPN

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, rras

I have a private VPN server in my VPS using windows Routing and Remote access. Now I cannot connect from two devices (e.g. IPad and my Laptop) in same time. I tried to change the properties but I've just got confused.

Can anybody help me?

---

I've created tho different users in windows to connect. Is there any better alternative way to create user just for VPN?

Comment: What VPN-Server are you using and how does the authentification work? Certificates? Password?

Comment: @SimonStrasser the authentication is windows authentication and I stetted up vps as [this](http://barbatunnel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20setup%20and%20configure%20PPTP%20VPN%20tunnel%20on%20Windows%202008%20R2%20to%20share%20internet%20traffic) said.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try to connect as the same user a 2nd time? Is there anything in the event logs on the server or laptop?